# Unit test mongo best option

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a question about the best way To write unit tests for testing Mongo with Python.

I initially used a pymongo inmemory db but after some reflection I wonder which is the best choice between this way or just with mock calls To the real db methods.

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out mongomock https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock

Once you actually need a running mongodb it's less of unit test and more of an integration test.